# PHP Value of Variable is undefined

Tags: php

I am getting " Notice: Undefined index:k" in the PHP code. K is the name of the text field and I am using $_GET[] method to get the value of k. In the below mentioned example I am trying to keep the value available even after the form is submitted. This Code runs fine for the first time but the second time it gives the above error.

```
    <form name="keywordquery" method="get" action="keywordsearch.php">
<fieldset class="fieldsetclass"><legend class="legendclass">Search by 
     Keywords</legend>
    <div id="searchbox">
   <input type="text" name="k" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['k'])){echo  
   htmlentities($_GET['k']);} ?>" style="border: 1px, thin; width:92%; "/> <input     
    type="image" style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 2px;" src="search.png" 
    value="submit" />
</div>
</fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>
  <table id="dataTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-    
   radius:20px; box-shadow: 9px 5px 8px #7E9044;">
  <tbody>    
<?php
        // PAGINATION Code. check if the starting row variable was passed in the 
    URL or not
  if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {

  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
  //otherwise we take the value from the URL
   } else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
   }


$k1 = $_GET['k'];

$term = explode(" ", $k1);
$query = "SELECT * FROM data ";
foreach ($term as $each) {
$i++;
    if($i==1)
    {
        $query .= "WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

else {
    $query .= " OR WHERE keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

}

$query .= "LIMIT $startrow, 1";

$connection = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxxx","");
if(!$connection)
echo "No database connected";
$dbase = mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxx", $connection);
if(!$dbase)
echo "No datatable connected";
$ourquery1 = mysql_query ($query);
if(!$ourquery1)
echo "No query found";

$row1 = mysql_num_rows ($ourquery1);
if ($row1 > 0)
{

    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ourquery1))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        $title = $result['title'];
        $link = $result['link'];
        $region = $result['region'];
        $sector = $result['sector'];
        $theme = $result['theme'];      
        echo "<td> <a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";
        echo "<h4>Sector: $sector&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Theme: $theme &nbsp; 
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br> Region: $region </td>";
    }
}


    echo "</tbody>";
       echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+1).'">Next</a>';
       echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow-1).'">Prev</a>';
```

Comment: Did you defined $i? In which line does this notice appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line:
$k1 = $_GET['k'];

with something like:
$k1 = isset($_GET['k'])? $_GET['k'] : $default_k_value;

Comment: Thanks after using the isset() the error doesn't appear anymore but when the code runs for the first time it doesn't show the first record and when I press the "Next" hyperlink then it displays the second record from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the complete form so it is tough to tell what is wrong but here is a hint.  Swap $_GET with $_REQUEST.

Example:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['k'])){echo  
   htmlentities($_REQUEST['k']);} ?>
```

If the form is using a POST method, the value would be in $_POST.  If the form uses a GET method, the value would be in $_GET.  However $_REQUEST will contain the form fields whether the form used POST or GET.

Comment: Thanks, Now I have added the form tags at the top of the code. I hope this will help you to solve my query.